# Срочно и быстро начать ExtJavaScript

Tags: yii, extjs

Здравствуйте. Нужно для проекта изучить ExtJS. ПисАться он будет под фреймворком Yii. Что можете посоветовать? С чего начать?

П.С. Вот нашел ExtJS для Yii ([Ссылка](http://ext4yii.com/)), но не знаю стоит ли ее использовать, ибо боюсь, что документации будет маловато для нее.

Comment: какие сроки на изучение? этот комбайн JS кода "срочно и быстро" нормально осилить не получится.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, сроки очень короткие) начинать (пусть помаленьку) надо будет через пару дней. Подскажите с чего начать? Например, при изучении yii самым сложным для меня было начало. Ибо не понимал совершенно что такое MVC. Везде находил только коды, а куда их вставлять даже не понимал. Вот и решил тут вопрос задать, дабы не наткнуться на подобное)  
П.С. Очень полезно было бы узнать как оно там устроено и в чем суть. По аналогии как yii использует MVC-шаблон. А не исходники и коды.
П.П.С. А что, ExtJS сильно сложный?)

Comment: Собственно, Hello world из под yii получился)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ExtJs  очень сложный и я бы начинал с него, а потом бы уже изучал бы пхпшные либы. Кстати, "срочно и быстро" -это тонны говнокода, к которому ненависть увеличивается с каждой строкой. Изучите все, а потом уже "срочные и быстрые" проекты делайте или найдите спеца с хорошим скидок по теме.  Удачи.